# Is producing a POS software in HTML/Javascript Viable?

Tags: javascript, html, linux, user-interface

My Family Owns a Restaurant and for various reasons, I want to make a POS software to replace the one they currently use. I am most comfortable making GUI in html/css so, if possible, I would like to take this path. I just have a few concerns.

1. Are There existing API's for dealing with printers, registers and credit card machines?
2. Can I make these applications run on Linux, and if so, how? (I Know Linux Can't Run .hta)
3. How would I go about connecting multiple terminals within the code?

I don't expect I walkthrough, but any information would be greatly appreciated.
Also, if using html/Javascript isn't viable, I would be open for suggestions. I am comfortable coding in C++ and Python, however I dont know of any easy ways to make GUI's with these languages.

Thanks!

Comment: So you run a local webserver on the network and build a web application.

Comment: If you are comfortable with Python, and web GUIs, you could try Django. Here is a project already started you could get ideas from: https://github.com/maxolasersquad/orthosie

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.  You could use HTML/JavaScript for the front-end,  but if you have multiple terminals, and printers etc. you will need a back-end infrastructure of some description which will need to be a server-side language; preferably something like ASP.net, PHP etc.

You'd need to design an architecture, design a database schema, work out the interfaces between all parts of the solution and design a user-friendly UI... the right place to go  to get this question answered is to enroll on a degree in computer science and get a few years experience in developing these systems!

Sorry to be snarky but this is a big undertaking;  if it were me, I'd not commit to doing it for a family business as my first web application. There are huge risks around payment card information and customer personal information that, if you get wrong, could lead to serious business risks.

Edit: A very quick google search lead me to http://www.unicentaopos.co.uk/  one of many free, open source POS systems.  the one linked seems specifically geared toward restaurants.

Comment: Coincidentally, I am currently in school for computer science. Sadly, you are probably right. I think at first I thought it would be just a lot of basic math and file I/O. I wouldn't even know where to start with a database. Thank you for the helpful response!

Comment: It is a good project for a CS person.  Much better than all the Hello World stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it with this.  But, it will depend upon your receipt printer, if you have a cash drawer.  For example, the TSP100 Receipt printers connect to a cash drawer and when printing, you can open the drawer.  It is independent of the application.

As for the backend, you obviously cannot do that with HTML/CSS.  You have to know how to design databases.